# Identify the building depicted in this charm

Tags: identify-this, architecture

Vintage Charm identify where this opera house is?

[image]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a picture attached. Try again?

Comment: Can you provide all the text that's on the charm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an opera house, it's a [Morris Column](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertising_column) used for posting advertisements. They're common in many European cities. The charm reflects the style of those in Paris, but it could be almost anywhere.

[image]

<sup>[TravelFranceOnline.com](https://www.travelfranceonline.com/morris-columns-paris-advertising-columns/)</sup>

Comment: do the words around the top (Martini on the charm, Tera something in this picture) mean something, or identify a location?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, @Kate. Images of the Parisian columns mostly have Theatre or Spectacle around the top and carry posters for theatre shows and other events. Martini, I'd guess, refers to the famous brand: yet more advertising. Perhaps the makers of the charm struck some product placement deal with Martini & Rossi.

Comment: Martini is an alcohol brand, they probably wanted to represent that in the charm.

Comment: Thank you everyone! So grateful. Sorry the photo didn’t show up for so long but I had uploaded it.